# Script does not work when place the function inside the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure, which receives a string and places it in the `WHERE` clause after processing it.

I created the function and when I call it from the body of a SQL statement, it returns the correct values:

```
('J1245',j3456','j1098')
```

However, when I call the function inside the `WHERE` clause as shown below, SQL does not show any records.

```
(Altcode in dbo.myfunction(@codes))
```

When I hard code it inside the `WHERE` clause, the SQL statement shows records.

```
(Altcode IN ('J1245',j3456','j1098'))
```

Comment: Function or procedure? Can you add code to the question please?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the function is returning a string (VARCHAR).  If we reference the function anywhere in a SQL statement, the value returned by the function serves as a scalar value. The contents of the value don't change that. Any punctuation, single quotes, backticks, parens, commas, keywords, identifiers, et al. that happen to appear in the string are just part of the value.

The parser sees the return from the function simply as a *single value*, not as part of the SQL text.

It's not possible (in a single statement) to make the value returned by a function "become" part of the SQL text to be parsed.

As an example, in the `WHERE` clause, if we write:

```
WHERE altcode IN ( myfunc() )
```

The function `myfunc` is going to be evaluated, and the return will be single value, of a certain datatype, for example maybe a VARCHAR. Any parens or commas within the value are *not* interpreted as part of the SQL text. Those are just characters that are within the value.

It's as if we wrote SQL like this:

```
 WHERE altcode IN ( ? )
```

And supplied a single value in place of the question mark placeholder. The SQL parser isn't seeing a list of values, it's not seeing any SQL to be executed. All the statement is seeing is a value.

It matters not one whit that we might supply a value that looks like SQL text, for example:

```
 WHERE altcode IN ( '(SELECT code FROM all_altcodes)' )
```

That would be equivalent to writing

```
 WHERE altcode = '(SELECT code FROM all_altcodes)'
```

And that is going to look for an exact match of `altcode` to the string literal.

---

Seems like there's a single quote missing in the value returned by the function, but maybe that's a typo in the question.

---

To get the string value returned by the function included as part of the SQL text, we would need to use *dynamic SQL*.

We would have to first call the function, and return the string.  And then do some string concatenation to come up with another string that contains the SQL statement we want to execute, and then execute that string as a SQL statement.

So that would be two *separate* statement executions... one to get the function evaluated; and a second statement that is dynamically constructed, as a string, incorporating the value returned by the function.

(The question is tagged "MySQL", but I suspect this question is actually regarding SQL Server (given the reference to `dbo.` ?)

Preparing and executing dynamic SQL is similar in MySQL and SQL Server, but there are differences in the syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. By the way, I have statements like ISNULL(CAST(BAR_MAIN.DischargeDate AS DATE),'') maybe the two single quotes causing the problem. Should I change these statements to two double quotes? I noticed does not like single quotes I had to changed 'CPT' TO "CPT". Thanks again

Comment: Single quotes are used to enclose string literals. If `sqlmode` doesn't include `ANSI_QUOTES`, then MySQL is more lenient and allows for double quotes around string literals. I don't think single quotes is a problem. I think the problem is that MySQL `ISNULL` function takes a single argument, and returns a boolean (1 or 0). Maybe we were meaning to replace a NULL value with an empty string using the `IFNULL` function?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Any idea why I am not able to see my store procedure in SSRS report builder? I am not able to see the SP I created after connecting to data source in the data set.